# Background image with an attachment of fixed inside a div with a radius getting warped during scroll

Tags: css, tailwind-css, background-image, border-radius

The background image is attached to a `div` with a fixed attachment and a top radius of `50px`. However, during scroll, it gets warped. When I removed the fixed attachment, it worked fine. But with the fixed attachment, it warps backward, creating a 3D effect. This effect only triggers when the `div` is a percentage down the viewport. The width of the viewport also affects how big or small this percentage is.

I want to avoid the warping or make it happen when the `div` enters the viewport instead of the sudden transition that starts the warping almost halfway down the viewport.

```
<div className="text-white h-[90vh] w-[100%] **bg-[url('src/assets/ContactSection/contactBg.jpg')]** bg-cover  **bg-fixed** flex flex-col justify-between  **rounded-t-[100px]**  ">
```

Comment: try using executable code snippets demonstratings your two cases and for the images, use [lorem ipsum](https://picsum.photos/) image souces instead of your local ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.